# app is using an old version of the Google Play Developer API

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I am developing a Xamarin Forms application that just has a few calls to the Maps and GeoLocation API. I am using the following packages in my application.

```
GeoCoordinate.NetCore               {1.0.0.1}           
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client {1.1.0}             
Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid           {3.2.0}             
Newtonsoft.Json                     {12.0.2}            
SearchPlaces                        {1.0.0}             
UXDivers.GorillaPlayer.SDK          {1.5.2}             
UXDivers.GorillaPlayer.SDK.AutoC... {1.5.0-Beta4}       
Xam.Plugin.Geolocator               {4.5.0.6}           
Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.D... {28.0.0.1}          
Xamarin.Forms                       {4.2.0.709249}      
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design      {28.0.0.1}          
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCo... {28.0.0.1}          
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4          {28.0.0.1}          
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView {28.0.0.1}          
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Media... {28.0.0.1}          
Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils  {28.0.0.1}          
Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs  {28.0.0.1}          
Xamarin.Essentials                  {1.2.0}             
Xamarin.Forms.Maps                  {4.2.0.709249}
```

when I upload this App to the Google Play for publishing, I see the following warning:

```
We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play Developer API. From December 1 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available. Update to version 3 before this date. Learn more
```

As far as I can see, there is nothing in my code that uses a version of `Google Play Developer API`. Closest I can see me using a Google API is from a 3rd party package called `SearchPlaces` where its using the following code to suggest the places from the search text.

```
    string CreatePredictionsUri(string newTextValue)
    {
        var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json";
        var input = Uri.EscapeUriString(newTextValue);
        var pType = PlaceTypeValue(placeType);
        var constructedUrl = $"{url}?input={input}&types={pType}&key={apiKey}";

        if (locationBias != null)
            constructedUrl = constructedUrl + locationBias;
        if (components != null)
            constructedUrl += components;

        return constructedUrl;
    }
```

can someone please help me understand why I am getting this warning in the google play console for my app.

**UPDATE 1**

Just wanted to add that I am also having this in my manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="<my API Key>" />
```

Comment: Your issue may be related to Google's new requirement for 64-bit version publishing applications. Here is a link that can help you solve this problem.

https://medium.com/swlh/64-bit-version-of-your-xamarin-native-or-xamarin-forms-android-app-477d0e637432

Comment: are you using Visual Studio to upload to Google Play? If you do an Ad-Hoc .apk and then manually upload, do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, I see the same error in both this situation.

Comment: Same thing here....did you figure it out?

Comment: @ledragon: No I am still struggling with this. Now I see we have passes the 1 Dec deadline and it not allowing me to upload my package in any form to the Google Play Store

Comment: @Kiran Thanks for the reply...I'm able to upload the APK file into the Play Console manually but I'll keep trying...how about we post here if either of us figures it out?